# Generate sphinx autodoc for files that contain encoded byte strings

Tags: python-3.x, encoding, utf-8, python-sphinx

I have several files that contain endcoded byte strings for example:

> variable_name = (b'encoded string')

however when I run `make html` to generate the auto documentation through Sphinx i receive the following error.

`Encoding error:`

`'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc0 in position 3: invalid start byte`

I still need sphinx to generate documentation for these files and for the rest of the files within my project instead of failing, or worst case scenario still generate documentation for every other file that does not contain these byte strings and just skip over the ones that do. Is there a configuration variable I can add to my conf.py file to get it to recognize the byte string or just overlook it all together, whether that means just not documenting that variable or skipping that entire file then continue on to document the remaining files?

Steps to reproduce:

1. create sphinx project with autodoc
2. add "vari = (b'\n$\x00\xc0\x91 \xa0l')" to any .py file
3. generate documentation with "make html" - it fails with the above error

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thank you in advance!

```
# Sphinx version: 2.1.2
# Python version: 3.5.2 (CPython)
# Docutils version: 0.14 
# Jinja2 version: 2.10.1
# Last messages:

# Loaded extensions:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/joshsullivan/.py_virtualenvs/verb_py3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sphinx/cmd/build.py", line 283, in build_main
    args.tags, args.verbosity, args.jobs, args.keep_going)
  File "/home/joshsullivan/.py_virtualenvs/verb_py3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sphinx/application.py", line 268, in __init__
    self._init_builder()
  File "/home/joshsullivan/.py_virtualenvs/verb_py3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sphinx/application.py", line 329, in _init_builder
    self.events.emit('builder-inited')
  File "/home/joshsullivan/.py_virtualenvs/verb_py3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sphinx/events.py", line 103, in emit
    results.append(callback(self.app, *args))
  File "/home/joshsullivan/.py_virtualenvs/verb_py3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/autoapi/extension.py", line 97, in run_autoapi
    patterns=file_patterns, dirs=normalized_dirs, ignore=ignore_patterns
  File "/home/joshsullivan/.py_virtualenvs/verb_py3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/autoapi/mappers/python/mapper.py", line 213, in load
    data = self.read_file(path=path)
  File "/home/joshsullivan/.py_virtualenvs/verb_py3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/autoapi/mappers/python/mapper.py", line 224, in read_file
    parsed_data = Parser().parse_file(path)
  File "/home/joshsullivan/.py_virtualenvs/verb_py3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/autoapi/mappers/python/parser.py", line 46, in parse_file
    return self.parse(node)
  File "/home/joshsullivan/.py_virtualenvs/verb_py3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/autoapi/mappers/python/parser.py", line 240, in parse
    data = parse_func(node)
  File "/home/joshsullivan/.py_virtualenvs/verb_py3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/autoapi/mappers/python/parser.py", line 227, in parse_module
    child_data = self.parse(child)
  File "/home/joshsullivan/.py_virtualenvs/verb_py3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/autoapi/mappers/python/parser.py", line 240, in parse
    data = parse_func(node)
  File "/home/joshsullivan/.py_virtualenvs/verb_py3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/autoapi/mappers/python/parser.py", line 72, in parse_assign
    value = self._encode(assign_value[1])
  File "/home/joshsullivan/.py_virtualenvs/verb_py3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/autoapi/mappers/python/parser.py", line 25, in _encode
    return _TEXT_TYPE(to_encode, self._encoding)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc0 in position 3: invalid start byte
```

my_file.py

```
'''This is my docstring'''
vari = (b'\n$\x00\xc0\x91 \xa0l')
```

my Conf.py file:

```
# Configuration file for the Sphinx documentation builder.
#
# This file only contains a selection of the most common options. For a full
# list see the documentation:
# http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/config

# -- Path setup --------------------------------------------------------------

# If extensions (or modules to document with autodoc) are in another directory,
# add these directories to sys.path here. If the directory is relative to the
# documentation root, use os.path.abspath to make it absolute, like shown here.
#
# import os
# import sys
# sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('.'))


# -- Project information -----------------------------------------------------

project = 'vstars'
copyright = '2019, S.P.A.D.E'
author = 'S.P.A.D.E'

# The short X.Y version
version = '1.0'

# The full version, including alpha/beta/rc tags
release = '1.0.1'


# -- General configuration ---------------------------------------------------

# If your documentation needs a minimal Sphinx version, state it here.
#
# needs_sphinx = '2.0.1'

# Add any Sphinx extension module names here, as strings. They can be
# extensions coming with Sphinx (named 'sphinx.ext.*') or your custom
# ones.
extensions = [
    'sphinx.ext.autodoc',
]

# Add any paths that contain templates here, relative to this directory.
templates_path = ['_templates']

# The suffix(es) of source filenames.
# You can specify multiple suffix as a list of string:
#
# source_suffix = ['.rst', '.md']
source_suffix = '.rst'

# The master toctree document.
master_doc = 'index'

# The language for content autogenerated by Sphinx. Refer to documentation
# for a list of supported languages.
#
# This is also used if you do content translation via gettext catalogs.
# Usually you set "language" from the command line for these cases.
language = None

# List of patterns, relative to source directory, that match files and
# directories to ignore when looking for source files.
# This pattern also affects html_static_path and html_extra_path.
exclude_patterns = ['_build', 'Thumbs.db', '.DS_Store']

# The name of the Pygments (syntax highlighting) style to use.
pygments_style = None


# -- Options for HTML output -------------------------------------------------

# The theme to use for HTML and HTML Help pages.  See the documentation for
# a list of builtin themes.
#
#html_theme = 'alabaster'

import sphinx_rtd_theme

html_theme = 'sphinx_rtd_theme'

html_theme_path = [sphinx_rtd_theme.get_html_theme_path()]

# Theme options are theme-specific and customize the look and feel of a theme
# further.  For a list of options available for each theme, see the
# documentation.
#
# html_theme_options = {}

# Add any paths that contain custom static files (such as style sheets) here,
# relative to this directory. They are copied after the builtin static files,
# so a file named "default.css" will overwrite the builtin "default.css".
html_static_path = ['_static']

# Custom sidebar templates, must be a dictionary that maps document names
# to template names.
#
# The default sidebars (for documents that don't match any pattern) are
# defined by theme itself.  Builtin themes are using these templates by
# default: ``['localtoc.html', 'relations.html', 'sourcelink.html',
# 'searchbox.html']``.
#
# html_sidebars = {}


# -- Options for HTMLHelp output ---------------------------------------------

# Output file base name for HTML help builder.
htmlhelp_basename = 'vstarsdoc'


# -- Options for LaTeX output ------------------------------------------------

latex_elements = {
    # The paper size ('letterpaper' or 'a4paper').
    #
    # 'papersize': 'letterpaper',

    # The font size ('10pt', '11pt' or '12pt').
    #
    # 'pointsize': '10pt',

    # Additional stuff for the LaTeX preamble.
    #
    # 'preamble': '',

    # Latex figure (float) alignment
    #
    # 'figure_align': 'htbp',
}

# Grouping the document tree into LaTeX files. List of tuples
# (source start file, target name, title,
#  author, documentclass [howto, manual, or own class]).
latex_documents = [
    (master_doc, 'vstars.tex', 'vstars\\_sphinx\\_documentation Documentation',
     'Joshua Sullivan', 'manual'),
]


# -- Options for manual page output ------------------------------------------

# One entry per manual page. List of tuples
# (source start file, name, description, authors, manual section).
man_pages = [
    (master_doc, 'vstars', 'vstars Documentation',
     [author], 1)
]


# -- Options for Texinfo output ----------------------------------------------

# Grouping the document tree into Texinfo files. List of tuples
# (source start file, target name, title, author,
#  dir menu entry, description, category)
texinfo_documents = [
    (master_doc, 'vstars', 'vstars Documentation',
     author, 'vstars', 'One line description of project.',
     'Miscellaneous'),
]


# -- Options for Epub output -------------------------------------------------

# Bibliographic Dublin Core info.
epub_title = project

# The unique identifier of the text. This can be a ISBN number
# or the project homepage.
#
# epub_identifier = ''

# A unique identification for the text.
#
# epub_uid = ''

# A list of files that should not be packed into the epub file.
epub_exclude_files = ['search.html']


# -- Extension configuration -------------------------------------------------
extensions = ['autoapi.extension']
# Document Python Code
autoapi_type = 'python'
autoapi_dirs = ['../']
```

my Index.rst file:

```
.. vstars documentation master file, created by
   sphinx-quickstart on Wed Jul  3 10:03:20 2019.
   You can adapt this file completely to your liking, but it should at least
   contain the root `toctree` directive.

Welcome to vstars's documentation!
==================================

.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 2
   :caption: Contents:



Indices and tables
==================

* :ref:`genindex`
* :ref:`modindex`
* :ref:`search`
```

my Makefile:

```
# Minimal makefile for Sphinx documentation
#

# You can set these variables from the command line.
SPHINXOPTS    =
SPHINXBUILD   = sphinx-build
SOURCEDIR     = .
BUILDDIR      = _build

# Generate __init__.py files for all subdirectories of vstars
init:
    find ../ -type d -not -path "../doc*" -exec touch {}/__init__.py \;

# Put it first so that "make" without argument is like "make help".
help:
    @$(SPHINXBUILD) -M help "$(SOURCEDIR)" "$(BUILDDIR)" $(SPHINXOPTS) $(O)

.PHONY: help Makefile

# Catch-all target: route all unknown targets to Sphinx using the new
# "make mode" option.  $(O) is meant as a shortcut for $(SPHINXOPTS).
%: Makefile
    @$(SPHINXBUILD) -M $@ "$(SOURCEDIR)" "$(BUILDDIR)" $(SPHINXOPTS) $(O)
```

folder structure:

- vstars

  - my_file.py
  - doc

    - Conf.py
    - Index.rst
    - Makefile

Comment: It's a syntax error to have a literal non-ASCII character in a `bytes` literal. I suspect the decoding error is caused by something else.

Comment: If I execute `b'\n$\x00\xc0\x91 \xa0l'.decode()` in a Python interactive session, I get the same error as in the question. But I cannot reproduce the problem when running Sphinx.

Comment: I see no reason why Sphinx would attempt to decode some arbitrary bytes object with UTF-8, since this is prone to failure. I would expect Sphinx to decode the source code with UTF-8 (default in Python 3), but that shouldn't cause this error, because the offending byte is escaped in the source (as `\xc0`, ie. four ASCII characters). Does Sphinx give you a traceback, ie. can you be sure it's the bytes literal that is causing the exception?

Comment: @lenz I added the tracebrack so you can see. It does seem to be caused by the bytes literal. I also confirmed this by simple commenting out the literal and executing the "make html" call and sphinx builds properly.

Comment: I can reproduce the problem. The last item in the stack trace refers to this line in the source code of the **Sphinx AutoAPI extension**: https://github.com/readthedocs/sphinx-autoapi/blob/master/autoapi/mappers/python/parser.py#L25.

Answer (score 1):

#### Cause

The UnicodeDecodeError stems from the Sphinx AutoAPI extension (https://sphinx-autoapi.readthedocs.io). The last item in the stack trace refers to line 25 in [autoapi/mappers/python/parser.py](https://github.com/readthedocs/sphinx-autoapi/blob/master/autoapi/mappers/python/parser.py#L25).

`_TEXT_TYPE` is an alias for `str`, so `_TEXT_TYPE(to_encode, self._encoding)` means `str(b'\n$\x00\xc0\x91 \xa0l', "UTF-8")` at runtime, equivalent to `b'\n$\x00\xc0\x91 \xa0l'.decode("UTF-8")`.

It looks like a bug. The problem does not occur with "vanilla" Sphinx.

#### Workaround

Add the following monkey patch to conf.py:

```py
from autoapi.mappers.python.parser import Parser

def patched_encode(self, to_encode):
    if self._encoding:
        try:
            if not(isinstance(bytes, to_encode)):  # <- The patch
                return _TEXT_TYPE(to_encode, self._encoding)
        except TypeError:
            # The string was already in the correct format
            pass

    return to_encode

Parser._encode = patched_encode
```